# fetch core data date as string to display on label

Tags: swift, date, core-data, fetch, appdelegate

I want my swift code to save 1 date in core data. on lbl1 i want the first core data date to be display. The label should only display the first date saved. Here is my code below which is not working. Nothing is being displayed on lbl1 when the function is called. I a link to my github profile below with this exact code.
https://github.com/redrock34/fetch

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    var foodItems = [Food]()
    var moc:NSManagedObjectContext!
    var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    var btn = UIButton()
    var lbl1 = UILabel()
  
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        moc = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        [btn,lbl1].forEach{
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),
            btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            
            lbl1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),
            lbl1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
            lbl1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor),
            lbl1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
          
            
        ])
        btn.backgroundColor = .orange
        lbl1.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
      
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addFoodToDatabase(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    @objc func addFoodToDatabase(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let foodItem = Food(context: moc)
        foodItem.added = NSDate() as Date
        
        
        
        appDelegate?.saveContext()
        
        place()
        
    }
    func place(){
    let foodRequest:NSFetchRequest<Food> = Food.fetchRequest()
         
         // 2

         
         // 3
         do {
             try foodItems = moc.fetch(foodRequest)
             
         }catch {
             print("Could not load data")
         }
        lbl1.text = moc.name
      
         
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to fix the compilation errors?

Comment: There are no errors nothing is showing up on the line

Comment: Well `lbl1.text = moc.name` doesn't make any sense, you should access `foodItems` instead.

Comment: what would I put   in foodItems lbl1.text = foodItems[]?

Comment: You should read up on [arrays](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107)